# Python/paho MQTT - not receiving messages

Tags: python, mqtt

I am new to using MQTT and I would like to run two Python programs simultaneously: one to publish messages to a topic and the other to print out the messages as they are published to the topic. However, the callback function to print out the message isn't working for me.

These are the two programs I have:

Publish messages:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected! Result code: " + str(rc))

client = mqtt.Client(client_id="clientID")
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.username_pw_set(username="username", password="password")
client.loop_start()
client.connect("node02.myqtthub.com", 1883)

while True:
    client.publish("my/topic", "test")
```

Subscribe to and print messages:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.payload.decode())

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected! Result code: " + str(rc))
    client.subscribe("my/topic")

client = mqtt.Client(client_id="clientID")
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.username_pw_set(username="username", password="password")
client.connect("node02.myqtthub.com", 1883)
client.loop_forever()
```

Could someone help me fix this issue?

Comment: Can you `telnet node02.myqtthub.com 1883` and see if you can actually reach the service? Would be a good first step to rule out any basic connection issues.

Comment: I have used their online viewer and I can see the messages show up there. Also, if I used https://node02.myqtthub.com to publish a message to the same topic, it is successfully shown by the second Python program ('Subscribe and print messages').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both programs are using `client_id="clientID"`; the [mqtt spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc384800405) states

> If the ClientId represents a Client already connected to the Server then the Server MUST disconnect the existing Client [MQTT-3.1.4-2].

So whichever app connects second will cause the first to be disconnected. To fix this change the client id in one of the apps.

Note: This is a comment on something obviously wrong. When asking a question please state what you see happening (any output, errors, what you have tried etc) because there may be another problem.

Comment: Thanks. Although both apps do successfully connect; it is just the on_message callback which doesn't run. Interestingly, it seems that the same clientID is required to connect to the broker I am using - have a look at: https://node02.myqtthub.com

Comment: Add an `on_disconnect` handler and I suspect you will find one of the connections is dropping (it's a common issue). If not enable logging (`on_log`) and add the info to your question. The website associated with this broker looks somewhat incomplete (maybe try `test.mosquitto.org`).

Comment: Sorry rechecked myqtthub.com site and it came up ok this time. They provide instructions covering [this issue](https://support.asplhosting.com/t/connecting-several-devices-with-same-credentials-how-to-avoid-mqtt-connection-replace-connection-replacement/37).