# MQTT PYTHON loop in connect_mqtt

Tags: python, python-3.x, mqtt, paho

I´m doing a Python script that recived and send mqtt messages, depend of the message recived, use ssh to send comands to a server. Each 3 minutes send a mqtt message to know that the server is turned ON.

But I have a problem... the script enter in an infinite loop in the function `def connect_mqtt()` after sending the first message that to notify that the server is already on and running
[image: here you can see how the code loops in the connect_mqtt function]

```
import time
from paho.mqtt import client as mqtt_client
from paramiko import SSHClient, AutoAddPolicy

broker = 'localhost'
port = 1883
user = "user"
passw = "pass"
topic = "LV-Automation/Server"
client_id = 'ServerPower'

msgState = f"ON"
msgON = f"Server_Encendido"
msgOFF = f"Server_Apagado"

rState = True


def connect_mqtt():
    def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
        if rc == 0:
            print("Connected to MQTT Broker!")
        else:
            print("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc)

    client = mqtt_client.Client(client_id)
    client.username_pw_set("user", "pass")
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.connect(broker, port)
    return client

def subscribe(client: mqtt_client):
    global rState
    def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
        global rState
        print(f"Received `{msg.payload.decode()}` from `{msg.topic}` topic")
        message = msg.payload.decode()
        if message == "OFF":
            rState = False
            client.publish(topic, msgOFF)
            client.publish(topic, "APAGADO")
            time.sleep(2)
            client1 = SSHClient()
            client1.load_system_host_keys()
            client1.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
            client1.connect('12.168.1.22', username= 'user', password= 'pass2w')
            stdin, stdout, stderr = client1.exec_command('powerdown')

        elif message == "Win10":
            client.publish(topic, "Iniciando Win 10 VM, resultado...")
            time.sleep(3)
            client2 = SSHClient()
            client2.load_system_host_keys()
            client2.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
            client2.connect('12.16.1.20', username= 'user', password= 'pass2w')
            stdin, stdout, stderr = client2.exec_command('virsh start Windows10')
            output = stdout.read()
            client.publish(topic, output)

        elif message == "Win10OFF":
            client.publish(topic, "Apagando Win 10 VM, resultado...")
            time.sleep(3)
            client3 = SSHClient()
            client3.load_system_host_keys()
            client3.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
            client3.connect('12.16.1.20', username= 'user', password= 'pass2w')
            stdin, stdout, stderr = client3.exec_command('virsh shutdown Windows10')
            output1 = stdout.read()
            client.publish(topic, output1)

    client.subscribe(topic)
    client.on_message = on_message



def prinRun(client):
    global rState
    client.publish(topic, msgON)
    while rState:
        client.publish(topic, msgState)
        time.sleep(250) # Pause for 3 minutes


def run():
    client = connect_mqtt()
    client.loop_start() # Start network loop in separate thread
    subscribe(client)
    prinRun(client)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

I´m know that i´m not using the best practice, but it have to work in some way

Comment: How many instances of the script are running (how many servers is it running on)

Comment: Also what do the broker logs show? (Please do not post pictures of text, post the actual text and use the toolbar to format it)

Comment: @hardillb I´m olnly running 1 instance of the script that runs with the start of ubuntu. Ok, thanks for the tip. I don´t see nothing in the mosquito logs with the IP of the ubuntu VM, but I received the first message of the script.

Comment: @Apha25 - you might need to set the logging level (e.g. `log_type all` in `mosquitto.conf`) but I'm confused by your comment "IP of the ubuntu VM," because you are connecting to `localhost` so the broker would be on the VM?. Is anything else connecting to the broker with the client id `ServerPower` (this is a [common cause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68749994/11810946) of the symptoms you describe)

Comment: @Brits thanks. I change the mosquito server ip for localhost, but in the server the script have the ip of the mosquito server.

Comment: @Brits you were right, it was another device with the same client id.  Thanks!